# To use two Facebook app ids on the same app for testing

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, testing

In order to test Facebook Events without modify the production data I need to use a second Facebook App Id inside of my iOS app. I want to do that automatically my Continuous Integration environment.

- Release Scheme -> Will have production Facebook app id.
- Debug Scheme -> Will have debug Facebook app id.

Do you use a **pre-building script to modify the info.plist** file? Do you know a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The App ID in the plist is a convenient way to set it up but the Facebook SDK allows you to set it inside the app as well.

Newer SDK:

`[FBSDKSettings setAppID:@"xxx"];`

Older SDKs:

`[FBSettings setDefaultAppID:@"xxxx"]`

That should allow you to switch between app ids when needed.

Comment: Thanks! With the new version of the SDK it has change to: 
    [FBSDKSettings setAppID:@"facebookId"];

Answer (score 2):

I use compiler constants testing:

```
#if defined(DEBUG)
    // Older Facebook SDK:
    // [FBSettings setDefaultAppID:@"debugID"]; 
    [FBSDKSettings setAppID:@"debugID"];
#else
    // Older Facebook SDK:
    // [FBSettings setDefaultAppID:@"productionID"];
    [FBSDKSettings setAppID:@"productionID"];
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks! With the new version of the SDK it has change to: 
    [FBSDKSettings setAppID:@"facebookId"];

Comment: You're right, I'm still using an older version in my own project.